# Button in ChromeDriver under Selenium not accepting click

Tags: angular, selenium, google-chrome, button, click

I'm running selenium, usinig the following nuGet packages (DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.3.11.0  NUnit.3.12.0  NUnit3TestAdapter.3.16.1  Selenium.Support.3.141.0  Selenium.WebDriver.3.141.0). I'm running on windows using Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit))

To date, everything is working apart from a few timing issues.
However, the button as described below refuses to accept any click.

```
<mat-card-actions _ngcontent-frq-c15="" class="mat-card-actions" style="margin-top: 3rem">
<button _ngcontent-frq-c15="" color="primary" mat-raised-button="" type="submit" class="mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary" ng-reflect-color="primary"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Submit</span>
    <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div>
    <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
<button _ngcontent-frq-c15="" mat-stroked-button="" type="reset" class="mat-stroked-button mat-button-base"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Clear</span>
    <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div>
    <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

I have tried everything from a code sense, see below

```
 string[] selectors =
  {
    ".mat-card-actions .mat-raised-button", ".mat-card-actions .mat-primary",
    ".mat-card-actions .mat-button-wrapper", ".mat-card-actions .mat-button-ripple"
  };
  //
  // string[] selectors = {".mat-card-actions .mat-raised-button"};
  foreach (string selector in selectors)
  {
    IWebElement submitButton = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
    submitButton.Click();

    try
    {
      submitButton.SendKeys(Keys.Space);
      submitButton.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      log.Error(ex.Message);
    }

    // This doesn't work
    // Configure the Action
    Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
    action.MoveToElement(submitButton).Perform();
    action.MoveToElement(submitButton).Click().Perform();


    // This doesn't work
    var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", submitButton);

    executor.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector(\".mat-raised-button\").click()");
  }
```

None of these work. Then I noticed that executing the following javascript in the chrome console window does not work.

```
document.querySelector(\".mat-raised-button\").click()"
```

However, this works fine in Chrome instances which are not being driven by Selenium. Is this a Chrome / Selenium or C# issue? All other button clicks are working fine in the application under test.
I've lost close on 2 days on this issue, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Comment: `document.querySelector(".mat-raised-button")` is pointing to the right element your run this in selenium triggered browser? And are you getting when things did not worked?

Comment: Yes, the example above has slashed. The key point is that when running in chrome, the javascript .click works. When running in ChromeDriver's (chrome) the .click does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo, we solved this one.
On the page, there are three cards (Company, User and Site). In our business logic, there is an option to use the same details for Company as Site, as they are very similar except for one field.
When developing the developer had re-used the same validator for the form (company) in the site area. This meant that that field was being checked in Site, but it didn't exist so the validation was failing. However, because there was no field on the UI the validation failing message was not visible.

Hopefully, this will save people time in the future, this type of bug can use up hours of team time. I would see a nice addition to Angular would be a console warning if the validation message was not visible to the user.